# Objective C - Navigation bar error + crash weird

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a weird situation.

I'm trying to add a navigation bar to my project by selecting the view. Editor --> embed in  --> Navigation Controller

Then I click on button with "push segue", and the app is crashing with the next error:

> Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
>   an instance of UINavigationController

The weird thing is that when I'm doing the same steps in a new project it's working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `UINavigationController`from the interface builder. Delete the table view controller and connect the `UINavigationController` to your first view controller as the "root view controller". Check that the navigation controller "Is Initial View Controller" in the attributes inspector.